# "Hack" in to localhost root directory from a VM web app

Tags: apache, directory, virtual-machine

I have apache VM web app running locally. It's red hat.

It's PHP based but the main page is index.html. I am able to to into sub-directories for images and such, I wanted to know if it is possible for me to gain access to the directories that contain the php code, probably just one level above the images directory. Because of index.html, it forces the load, and I am unable to see server files.

Comment: No. It's not. If you could go above the root folder, there would be no security for your web server at all, would there? Your design is wrong.

Comment: I believe he just curious to know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there used to be a trick called [dot-dot-traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) that could do this.  Basically you put two dots into a URL and climb above the web root.  Something like `http://www.example.com/../../../../etc/shadow` . Occasionally a new way to exploit the vulnerability is discovered, but mostly it is rare.  Unless you're running an old server, you should be pretty safe.